# GWT - event.getX() and event.getClientX()

Tags: gwt

I added click handler to flowpanel as follows

```
this.addDomHandler(new ClickHandler(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {



                Window.alert("event.getX()="+event.getX()+" event.getY()="+event.getY());
                Window.alert("event.getClientX()="+event.getClientX()+" event.getClientY()="+event.getClientY());

            }

            },ClickEvent.getType());
```

... as I could get it getX() returns mouse position within flowpanel but getClientX() returns another value and I couldn't get the value is coming from. So my question is what is the getClientXY() methods are used for?

P.S
GWT 2.2/2.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [javadoc](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/MouseEvent.html#getClientX%28%29) is clear:

`getClientX`: Gets the mouse x-position within the **browser window**'s client area.

`getX`: Gets the mouse x-position relative to the event's **current target element**.

So, you can use getClientX to get the absolute `left` position of some element.

Comment: Thanks. It is more clear for me now :) Could you give the online docs link?

Comment: I've added the link in the answer. Click "javadoc".